# Android custom View + standard element...how?

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

I've been working away at an Android app for a while now and I'm trying to get a UI off the ground for it. I've created already created several with the standard XML + Java approach, but one screen requires a custom View (using draw to create a sort of grid) with a small TextView beneath it and two buttons beneath that. It doesn't seem that this custom View can reasonably extend existing ones (although if it can, that might make things easier), so I'm left with either using the XML + Java layout and integrating the custom View into that or using strict Java to create the layout. After digging around with both (and getting nothing but crashes or blank screens with the former), I've been mucking around with the Java layout, but can't seem to get anything to show up beneath the custom View.

I've dug through many tutorials, but I can't seem to get anything working from them and the Android developer resources aren't very detailed with this sort of thing. If someone can point me in the right direction to get this functioning, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom views from XML:

```
<com.mypackage.MyCustomView android:layout_width="wrap_content" ... />
```

Comment: I've already tried the custom view in XML with the full package name. It crashes out with several errors, most of them seemingly inflater-related. I just can't get this thing to play nice with XML. I was hoping to just lay the thing out strictly with Java, and while that doesn't crash, I can't get the bloody buttons to show up below. The best I've been able to do is get them to lay over the custom view, which isn't going to work, of course.

Comment: You're probably missing the right constructor: you need to implement the constructor(s) that take an AttributeSet as a parameter.

Comment: Is there any way to abbreviate the package name? If I add xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mybiz.package" I should be able to write <foo:MyView> and not <foo:com.mybiz.package.MyView> right?

Comment: Namespaces are never used for tag names, only for attributes. The tag name is always the fully qualified class name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a custom view with many standard views like buttons below it. The custom view is simply added into a linerLayout: http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/07/2d-graphics-with-effects_11.html